# IE7-8 resize filter

Tags: css, filter

Why is this not resizing my image in IE7-8????

```
#carousel ul li #myImage {
  background: url("../img/myImage.png") no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/myImage.png',sizingMethod='scale');
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/myImage.png',sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Comment: Is this in a CSS file? If it is, you may not load the filter at all, because the filter might load not relative to the css file, but to the page, so try absolute path for the filter.

Comment: Please explain further..

Comment: Don't use `src='../img/myImage.png'` but `src='/path/to/img/myImage.png'`